# Any good relational database tutorials?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am looking for how to build a relational mysql database, and I would like to follow a tutorial.

I need one that shows how to make multiple tables, and link those together using an id.  Which I can later use to grab relational data from the different tables.  This is probably easy stuff, but I am just learning about databases.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is based on Oracle SQL so the syntax will vary slightly, but this is a great conceptual overview: http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a really good one for MySQL beginners.  Nettus have some really great articles on Internet technologies.  They are the new w3school.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, I'd start with the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/) [Tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tutorial.html), and then perhaps over to [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net).